# Switch screens on Slax Linux (xrandr, FluxBox)

Tags: live-usb, multi-monitor, xrandr, fluxbox

I use Slax Linux as a Live Linux on a USB drive and I have a problem with multiple monitor configuration.

My computer has two screens, this is the output of `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3200 x 1200, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-1 connected primary 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95*+
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DVI-I-2 connected 1280x1024+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 376mm x 301mm
   1280x1024     60.02*+  75.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

When Slax is started, it looks like this: (50% scale)
[image: Screenshot 1]
Which is perfect, except, to get the mouse on the left screen, I have to move it out of the right of the right screen. So I want to switch the screens. First I tried:

```
xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --auto --output DVI-I-2 --auto --left-of DVI-I-1
```

Now the mouse moves the right way, but the screens look like this:

[image: Screenshot 2]

If I do instead:

```
xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --off --output DVI-I-2 --off
xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --auto --output DVI-I-2 --auto --left-of DVI-I-1
```

It seems to work at first, my screens looks like the first picture and the mouse moves okay. But when I click on the four squares to start a program, the screens look like this:

[image: Screenshot 3]

How can I switch the screens and get FluxBox (version 1.3.5) to work normally? Note that I'll be using this installation on different computers, so I don't want any permanent configuration, just a few lines of code that I can run after startup when I'm using this particular computer. Editing of configuration files is allowed though, Slax uses a temporary file system and changes will be lost on reboot anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Rubber duck debugging at its best. [Found it here.](https://pseudoscripter.wordpress.com/2015/05/07/restart-fluxbox-off-the-command-line/)

The solution is to change `~/.fluxbox/init` permanently. Change `session.screen0.allowRemoteActions: false` to 
`session.screen0.allowRemoteActions: true`. FluxBox needs to be restarted for this to work, or simply do a reboot.

Then, when needed FluxBox can be restarted after a `xrandr` command. In my case:

```
xrandr --output DVI-I-1 --auto --output DVI-I-2 --auto --left-of DVI-I-1
fluxbox-remote restart
```